# Como fazer para "explode" as vezes receber mais valores?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um código que lê um txt e salva no banco de dados, só que as vezes ele irá receber mais valores, exemplo:

**Tenho o seguinte txt:**

```
|texto|texto|texto|
|texto|texto|texto|texto|
```

Se eu usar para receber os 4 campos, ele dá erro no que têm só 3, o que poderia ser feito?

**Segue o meu código:**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

include_once("conexao.php");

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode('|', $linha);

    $REG = $valor[1];
    $COD = $valor[2];
    $UNID = $valor[3];
    $QTD = $valor[4];
    $cod1 = "INSERT INTO temp (REG, COD, UNID, QTD) VALUES ('$REG','$COD_ITEM','$UNID','$QTD')";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terá que tratar os valores, claro que em conjunto com o seu banco de dados.

Um exemplo:

```
$REG = $valor[1];
$COD = $valor[2];
$UNID = $valor[3];
(isset($valor[4])) ? $QTD = $valor[4]: $QTD = NULL;
```

Assim, se não tiver o 4o valor, irá levar `null`.

Ou pode retornar `0` caso não queira `null` e/ou o seu banco exija valor:

```
(isset($valor[4])) ? $QTD = $valor[4]: $QTD = 0;
```

---

Como você sabe melhor que todos o que tem no valor, então poderá tratar da melhor forma, exemplos:

```
(isset($valor[4]) && $valor[4] > 0) ...
($valor[4] > 0) ...
(strlen($valor[4]) > 0) ...
```